# Variable inside JS expression in React

Tags: reactjs, syntax, jsx

This is my React code:

```
const colors = ["RED", "BLUE", "GREEN", "YELLOW"];

// in class component 

constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  // these are filled in somewhere else in the code, but not shown here
  this.state = {
    redFiles: [],
    blueFiles: [],
    greenFiles: [],
    yellowFiles: []
  }
}
```

```
//somewhere else in the code:

render() {
  <div>
    {colors.map( color => 
      {this.state._____Files.length}      // problem area: how do I put color.toLowerCase() variable within that blank 
  </div>
}
```

In the indicated "problem area", how do I put the `color.toLowerCase()` variable in that blank such that we have `this.state.redFiles.length`, `this.state.blueFiles.length`, `this.state.greenFiles.length`, and `this.state.yellowFiles.length`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing an object property with a dynamically-computed name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/accessing-an-object-property-with-a-dynamically-computed-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this

```
{colors.map(color => (
      <div key={color}>
        {this.state[color.toLowerCase() + "Files"].length}
      </div>
    ))}
```